# Calculating hour difference iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have written like this to calculate hour difference.

```
+ (NSInteger)hoursBetweenDate:(NSDate*)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate *)toDateTime
{
    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSHourCalendarUnit startDate:&fromDate
             interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSHourCalendarUnit startDate:&toDate
             interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];

    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

    return [difference hour];
}
```

Problem is that if input is like this,

> > 2016-03-09 07:58:39 +0000 (fromDateTime)
> >     2016-03-09 09:07:44 +0000 (toDateTime),

difference is always 2 hours. Actually, it should be 1 hour and 10 minute. As a result, I only want to show 1 hour. Is there a way to round up or down?

Comment: You could change the minutes from `fromDateTime` and `toDateTime` to 0 before you calculate the difference, then the result would be one hour.

Comment: @FabioBerger I think he wants the number of hours between dates, in which case this won't be enough (think 25 hours).

Comment: @Eiko Yes he wants the hours between dates, but his problem are the minutes. If you set the minutes of both dates to 0 then the calculations of the calendar are correct, not matter how far the dates are apart.

Comment: @FabioBerger Ah right. Still a rather complex approach to what can be solved by a difference and an integer devision. :)

Comment: @Eiko I have to agree yours is pretty neat (+1 for that) and should probably be the accepted answer. But it doesn't hurt to have a bit of experience with calculating with dates and since the OP already wrote this more complex code it's not that complicated to implement my suggestion. To each his own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just interested in the "unformatted" number of hours between to dates, you can use `NSTimeInterval` and calculate it easily.

```
+(int)fullHoursBetweenDate:(NSDate *)date1 andDate:(NSDate *)date2 {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    return (int)interval / 3600;
}
```

Comment: What will happen if I don't set timezone in your method?

Comment: Timezone and calendar are irrelevant for time difference calculation. One hour is always one hour, and NSDate will take care of that, as it pays attention to the timezone.

Comment: @vadian Can you give a clear reference or example when it's wrong? NSDate should take this into account, and I'd consider manually fiddling with components would make daylight savings a problem.

Comment: @Eiko, you are right, the calculation is correct. I removed my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

This small NSCalendar extension should do a trick for you.

```
extension NSCalendar {
    func hoursBetweenDates(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Int {
        let days  = differenceInDates(startDate, endDate: endDate, unit: .Hour)
        return days
    }

    func differenceInDates(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate, unit: NSCalendarUnit) -> Int {
        let startUnit    = ordinalityOfUnit(unit, inUnit: .Era, forDate:startDate)
        let endUnit      = ordinalityOfUnit(unit, inUnit: .Era, forDate:endDate)
        let difference   = endUnit-startUnit

        return difference
    }
}
```

And Obj-C version can be written as follow:

```
@interface NSCalendar (Duration)
-(NSNumber *)hoursBetweenStartDate:(NSDate*)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate*) endDate;
@end

@implementation NSCalendar (Duration)
-(NSNumber *)hoursBetweenStartDate:(NSDate*)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate*) endDate {

    NSUInteger startUnit = [self ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:startDate];
    NSUInteger endUnit   = [self ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:endDate];

    return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: (endUnit - startUnit)];
}
@end
```

Comment: Please provide the "small NSCalendar extension" in objective c :)

Answer (score 0):

You extracted out only the **hour** component (`NSHourCalendarUnit`) before you compare, that's why it's always 2 (*9 - 7*). Added `NSMinuteCalendarUnit` the result would be 1:

```
+ (NSInteger)hoursBetweenDate:(NSDate*)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate *)toDateTime
{
    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit startDate:&fromDate
                 interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit startDate:&toDate
                 interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];

    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

    return [difference hour];
}
```

Also, if you are targeting iOS 8+, you should use `NSCalendarUnitHour` and  `NSCalendarUnitMinute` instead as `NSHourCalendarUnit` and `NSMinuteCalendarUnit` were deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this function as per your requirement

```
+(NSString*)timeDifference:(NSDate*)startDate endDate:(NSDate*)endDate{

NSDateComponents *components;
NSInteger days;
NSInteger hour;
NSInteger minutes;
NSString *strDuration;


components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute
                                             fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];
days = [components day];
hour=[components hour];
minutes=[components minute];

if(days>0){

    if(days>1){
        strDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days",days];
    }
    else{
        strDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d day",days];

    }
    return strDuration;
}

if(hour>0){

    if(hour>1){
        strDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours",hour];
    }
    else{
        strDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hour",hour];

    }
    return strDuration;
}

if(minutes>0){

    if(minutes>1){
        strDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes",minutes];
    }
    else{
        strDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute",minutes];

    }
    return strDuration;
}

return @"";

}
```